# Number detecting in javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, bitcoin

So I had visited a lot of websites and still havent found anything on this topic. I want to write a function (in javascript)  that checks the output of this code:

```
function mineHash(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = '01';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

console.log(mineHash(256));
```

and if the output has **70 or more 0s at the start** it logs: `("Valid hash found!")`

Comment: What is `makeid`?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that! @NikitaSkrebets

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: I'd say you can use [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and a long string of 70 zeroes. Or match it against this regex: `^0{70}`

Comment: Yes, It helped, but how do I make it to work with the output of the minehash function?

Edit:
Can you please put it in an answer @PeterB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a string of 70 zeroes and check if the `mineHash` result starts with these 70 zeroes. I also output the hash so we can check the result.

```js
function mineHash(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = '01';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

const manyZeroes = '0'.repeat(70);
const hash = mineHash(256);
console.log(hash)
console.log(hash.startsWith(manyZeroes) ? 'Valid hash found!' : 'NOT a valid hash!')

// or an alternative suggested by Peter B:
console.log(/^0{70}/.test(hash) ? 'Valid hash found!' : 'NOT a valid hash!')
```